# Why ever use any of the tests of hypotheses when we can just regress everything?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, modeling

So far in every data set I've worked with, regressing with only 1 predictor variable has yielded p-values extremely close to the one I get when running it with a test of hypothesis such as pearson's, mann U whitney, T test etc.

My question is, why do we use these "simpler" tests when we can simply regress everything anyways?

To clarify, instead of doing a Chi2 on "variable a" and "variable b", I just run a logistical regression (as an example).

Comment: It’s because it’s easier to explain individual tests to beginners, so that’s what most people know. A more experienced statistician knows that the t-test can be written as a regression on an indicator variable, but that makes it harder to communicate with the less experienced statisticians who are our bosses, investors, reviewers, etc.

Comment: I would think it would be the opposite. The vast amount of tests muddy the waters instead of simply saying "we ran a regression, you know, the one we always run".

Comment: @Paze: plus it allows to adjust for confounders.

Comment: And then your reviewer will write, “We typically evaluate this with a t-test. Please include a citation for using this method in a similar context and give a discussion about why you prefer this statistical method.”

Comment: @Dave: valid point but these kind of rebuttals are usually easy to solve by pointing out the equivalence (if it *is* equivalent).

Comment: Doing the more simple tests allows you to avoid doing heavy model diagnostics.

Comment: For making furniture, why use screws, bolts, glue, dovetails, tenons, or any other technique to join pieces of wood when we can simply hammer everything together with enough nails?